# Aurelia HttpClient.Fetch to get token from Auth0 but works fine in Postman

Tags: aurelia, auth0

I have no trouble getting a bearer token returned when using Postman. However, when using Aurelia, I receive a status 200 with "OK" as the only response. I see that the Request Method is still "OPTIONS". I see this in the Chrome Console:

```
Failed to load https://------.auth0.com/oauth/token: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

But, from what I can see the headers shown in the response and from what I'm seeing everything looks like it's there.

Here's what I receive from Postman:

```
Response: Status 200 OK
JSON:
{
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci...{shortened for brevity}",
"expires_in": 86400,
"token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Here's code from Aurelia:

```
private getToken() {
    var postData = { "client_id": API_CONFIG.clientId, "client_secret": API_CONFIG.clientSecret, "audience": API_CONFIG.audience, "grant_type": "client_credentials" };
    this.http.fetch('https://kimberlite.auth0.com/oauth/token', {
        credentials: 'omit',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000/'
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }).then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            localStorage.setItem('api_access_token', data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('api_expires_at', new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in);
        });
}
```

[image]
[image]

I've searched and haven't found anything that's helped me get passed this. What am I missing? Any help greatly appreciated

After reading Jesse's comment below, I removed the header for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and receive the same 200 OK. However, receive error in Google Chrome `Origin 'localhost:3000'; is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."`.

After reading other questions, I attempted removing all headers and I receive a **401 Unathorized** with the following response **{{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}**

```
    private getToken() {
    var postData = { "client_id": API_CONFIG.clientId, "client_secret": API_CONFIG.clientSecret, "audience": API_CONFIG.audience, "grant_type": "client_credentials" };
    let http = new HttpClient();
    http.fetch('https://kimberlite.auth0.com/oauth/token', {
        credentials: 'omit',
        //headers: {
        //    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        //},
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }).then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            localStorage.setItem('api_access_token', data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('api_expires_at', new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in);
        });
}
```

ok, I just tried in Firefox, using only the 'Content-Type' header and received expected response. Is there something with Chrome (which most users are going to be using) that I need to be aware of? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the `access-control-allow-origin` header on the request. In a CORS request, the server endpoint needs to set this header on the response of your OPTIONS request.

---

The way that Cross-Origin Resource Sharing works, is that the client first makes an OPTIONS call to the server endpoint. The server endpoint should be configured to use CORS, and have a list of origins that are allowed (or simply a `*` to allow all origins). Then on the response to this OPTIONS request, the *server* will set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000` to indicate the origin is allowed to make the request. You can see this in your response too:

[image: Response header]

The client then proceeds to make the GET or POST call to the same endpoint and actually retrieve/store the data.

In your case, if you make the request using the Aurelia fetch client, you don't need to set a header to do this. You can simply do the following:

```
private getToken() {
    var postData = { "client_id": API_CONFIG.clientId, "client_secret": API_CONFIG.clientSecret, "audience": API_CONFIG.audience, "grant_type": "client_credentials" };
    this.http.fetch('https://kimberlite.auth0.com/oauth/token', {
        credentials: 'omit',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }).then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            localStorage.setItem('api_access_token', data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('api_expires_at', new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in);
        });
}
```

Comment: Jesse, first I want to say thank you for the details of your answer...the explanation helped fill in some gaps that I am having. Unfortunately, nothing changes when I remove that header. I've tried to move the code around in far too many ways and I only end up with a 200 OK (ONLY)...or a 401 unauthorized when I move the same code around, say if I add an interceptor. Again, I appreciate the details, they are very helpful. But, it doesn't change anything unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you're getting a 401 on the request, it looks like the endpoint requires a form of authentication. I'm not familiar with the endpoint you're using but maybe there's some documentation on the authentication?

Comment: I was thinking if the 401 is coming back, then I've passed the pre-flight. The part that is boggling to me is I'm using the exact same credentials that returns the expected answer when I'm using PostMan; it's just trying with Aurelia that is not returning.

Comment: Postman is not making a CORS request, that's why it works.  That said, I am having the same problem. I am not using Aurelia, but AngularJS.  Now here the strange part one Auth0 tenant works, and another doesn't.